# A cloud data solution which allows for known fixed maximum costs?

Tags: cloud-hosting, cloud-storage

I have a multi-user application, and would like to serve (say) millions of small (~10KB) blobs of data from someone else's servers without using my own network bandwidth. The trouble is, I haven't found any cloud data providers that offer a way to ensure that the costs don't exceed a fixed amount.

Ideally, I would like to have 'buckets' for each user, which each user accesses more-or-less directly (i.e. requests are not proxied from a server of mine), and set the restrictions that:

- the buckets cannot exceed a fixed size on disk
- *either:*

  - a maximum number of GET/POST/LIST/etc. requests can be made per bucket per time period
  - a maximum amount of network usage is allowed per user per time period

Users would access the buckets directly and be cut off when their limits have been reached (via an HTTP 429 response, maybe). This would let me ensure a maximum amount of storage and data transfer per user, thus I'd expect a fixed maximum cost.

It seems possible to implement the accounting logic portion myself, polling a cloud server's logs periodically, and maintaining my own meta request database. But I'd rather not go that route if I can help it.

Are there any cloud data providers that fit these requirements? Any software offerings that provide these features on top of cloud data providers that don't otherwise offer them?